# Are there any native gtkmm classes to Queue commands/data from the signal handler functions of the widgets?

Tags: c++, gtk, cairo, gtkmm, pango

I have constructed a Gtkmm GUI with miscellaneous widgets. On invoking the signal, each widget is intended to construct a "string" using user input data that is sent over the network. Thus I think, the commands have to pass through a single queuing mechanism (queue, ring buffer, etc) to avoid contention. Is there a native queue or ring buffer class in gtkmm that performs this function? I was thinking more on these lines

`http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/glib/glib-Asynchronous-Queues.html`

P.S:

I am unable to find an equivalent wrapper here
 `http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/2.22/gtkmm-tutorial.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/unstable/thread_2thread_8cc-example.html

Answer (score 1):

Glib is wrapped seperately as glibmm.  If the functionality is wrapped, you should find it there.